# SQL: Selecting NOT NULL data with a column that is shared and changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Table1) that has an ID that is shared from multiple-inserts:

> ```
> ID  | RefID | Field_Name | Field_Value | Type
>  1  |    1  | NumbAmt    | 1111        | INT
>  2  |    1  | LocAdd     | 123 Street  | String
>  3  |    1  | LocDesc    | Something   | String
>  4  |    1  | LocHidden  | Useless     | Hidden
> ```

I can't use the ID since it is made from the inserts, the RefID is the main thing used to narrow down this data to all those with the **RefID = 1 AND Type != 'Hidden'**.

Whenever I do a case statement query:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'NumbAmt' THEN Field_Value END Amt,
  CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'LocAdd' THEN Field_Value END Address,
  CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'LocDesc' THEN Field_Value END Description
FROM Table1
WHERE RefID = 1
  AND Type IN ('INT','String')
```

It returns the results like:

> ```
>     Amt     |   Address    | Description
> 1111        |    NULL      | NULL
> NULL        | 123 Street   | NULL
> NULL        |    NULL      | Something
> ```

My question is, how would I gather all the data but have it split into separate columns without all the NULLs showing? (My assumption leads me to believe a temp table)

Or show up like:

> ```
>  Amt     |   Address  | Description
> 1111     | 123 Street | Something
> ```

Comment: Are the Field Names stable, or do you need a solution that can handle additional values?

Comment: They're based on the insert for the field the data comes from on screen to the database.

So the LocAdd came from a text-field called address, NumbAmt from a field asking for a Limit and then a description textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- Join the table to itself
- Use PIVOT
- Subquery all fields in the SELECT list
- Use OUTER APPLY for each field
- Use CTE
- **Consider to rethink your scheme!**

**JOINS**

```
 SELECT
  T1_RefID.RefID, 
  T1_NumbAmt.FieldValue AS NumbAmt,
  T1_LocAdd.FieldValue AS LocAdd
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT RefID FROM Table1) T1_RefID
  LEFT JOIN Table1 T1_NumbAmt
    ON T1_RefID.RefID = T1_NumbAmt.RefID AND T1_NumbAmt.FieldName = 'NumbAmt' AND T1_NumbAmt.Type != 'Hidden'
  LEFT JOIN Table1 T1_LocAdd
    ON T1_RefID.RefID = T1_LocAdd.RefID AND T1_LocAdd.FieldName = 'LocAdd' AND T1_LocAdd.Type != 'Hidden'
  /* And so on*/
```

**PIVOT**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    RefID, FieldName, FieldValue
  FROM
    Table1
  WHERE
    Type != 'Hidden'
) AS src
PIVOT (
  MAX(FieldValue)
  FOR FieldName IN (NumbAmt, LocAdd, LocDesc)
) AS PVT
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61335/8)

Comment: I was blissfully unaware of pivot, I am going to give that a shot as well!

Would definitely love choosing multiple answers because I know this will have multiple approaches. I do think the database was setup for the original purpose, I just don't think knowing that a reporting system would be implemented would of led to the state that I am currently working in.

Thank you though! :)

Comment: Doodely: You are welcome. @Lukas Eder: Thanks :) (BTW: the best choice is to rethink/rebuild your scheme.. This scheme will led to additional headaches in the future)

Comment: @Pred, if it wouldn't be too much trouble, how would one display multiple sets of data using PIVOT?

Based on the information we already have established, if someone where to go back in under that same RefID and add another entry that would make the insert it seems PIVOT is based on the most current thing entered?

Comment: You can build the PIVOT dynamically with string functions or CLR functions. The 'dynamic pivot' feature does not exist in SQL Server. You have to modify your query each time when a new FieldName arrives, or you can filter the inner select based on the known FieldName values. As I said: this scheme will led to additional headaches :) (There is no 'perfect' solution, because you have to know which 'fields' are already added (or could be added) to retrieve the values as a table, or you have to build the query dynamically).

Comment: Well I have been notified that I am allowed to make a view to help sort all of this data that I will be accessing and utilizing. So, I do thank you again and agree with the headaches that would of came from constantly altering PIVOT for every new entry that would be looped through.

Comment: You are welcome. Have fun with it :) (And try to get permission to rethink/rebuild this part of your database)

Answer (score 2):

You could of course write this statement:

```
WITH Record(Field_Value, Field_Name) AS (
  SELECT Field_Value, Field_Name FROM Table1 WHERE RefID = 1
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT Field_Value FROM Record WHERE Field_Name = 'NumbAmt') Amt,
  (SELECT Field_Value FROM Record WHERE Field_Name = 'LocAdd')  Address,
  (SELECT Field_Value FROM Record WHERE Field_Name = 'LocDesc') Description
FROM
  Record
```

But I strongly recommend avoiding the [entity-attribute-value anti-pattern](http://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back), and redesigning your schema.

Comment: The real query has a lot of joins in as well, I have considered using multiple selects to gather the data, it would just be a huge query for 3 values.

Comment: @Doodely: One more reason to sanitise your schema :-) Anyway, the common table expression (CTE) should allow SQL Server to perform some optimisations in order to cache the "temp table" `Record`. Also, you should be able to move all those joins into the CTE, avoiding repetition...

Comment: For fairness, this database that I am working with (and making very basic information for on here) does belong to another developer who up until this point was not aware that we would have a reporting system to print out data from the database to a PDF document.

With the way it is currently setup compared to the norm I agree with you, but since I am working with this I have to find something.

Comment: ++ Got cut off, but I will select your answer as the most appropriate because it showed me a very interesting article (thank you!) and did verify my earlier guess of just using multiple selects.

Comment: @Doodely: I can really recommend Bill Karwin's book. It's an eye-opener to so many common SQL mistakes...

Answer (score 2):

You could create a view for this and use it

```
SELECT T.RefID, TAmt.Field_Value as Amt, TAddress.Field_Value as Address, TType.Field_Value as Type FROM
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT RefID
    FROM
        Table1
    WHERE
        Type IN ('INT', 'String')
) T
LEFT JOIN
    Table1 AS TAmt
ON
    T.RefID = TAmt.RefID
    AND TAmt.Field_Name = 'NumbAmt'
LEFT JOIN
    Table1 AS TAddress
ON
    T.RefID = TAddress.RefID
    AND TAddress.Field_Name = 'LocAdd'
LEFT JOIN
    Table1 AS TType
ON
    T.RefID = TType.RefID
    AND TType.Field_Name = 'LocDesc'
```

Comment: Hmm, how does this perform, with the `DISTINCT` in the derived table?

Answer (score 1):

Use group by on the key field, and some aggregate function to promote the correct value over the nulls (I believe max will do, but cannot test this where I sit presently)

```
SELECT 
  RefID,
  MAX( CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'NumbAmt' THEN Field_Value ELSE NULL END ) Amt,
  MAX( CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'LocAdd' THEN Field_Value ELSE NULL END ) Address,
  MAX( CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'LocDesc' THEN Field_Value ELSE NULL END ) Description
FROM Table1
GROUP BY RefID
```